# Using RESTful api written in java on wordpress

Tags: java, php, wordpress, rest

Hi I have a web application I wrote in netbeans that utilizes some rest API. I migrated this web app into wordpress and google cloud but I notice that when I try to test the rest API on postman I get a wordpress page not found error. I have a feeling that it is because java doesn't work on apache. I used xampp and tested it with tomcat, working fine, but it doesnt work on apache. Is there a way to connect this or would I have to rewrite the rest api in php? Thanks

Comment: Java works with Apache Tomcat, not Apache HTTPd. Are you saying your single API is written in part in Java and in part PHP? How did that happen?

Comment: No, it is written in only java. The problem is that when I try to access the service via the link 'rest/dbservices/insert', I get a page not found

Comment: I can't be the only one confused about what you're asking then. If your API is in Java, then run it on Tomcat. It won't run on HTTPd. That begs the question, what's the actual problem? Where does PHP and HTTPd actually come into this?

Comment: because wordpress uses apache http i think, the api service won't work. What I'm asking is if there is a workaround to make it work or would I need to rewrite the api in php so that wordpress can support it

Comment: Right? So host the API on Tomcat, and Wordpress on HTTPd. In theory they wouldn't normally even be on the same box. I assume the API is accessible via HTTP, so there should be no problem just running them off different ports on the same box.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to wordpress so my understanding is not that great. I have a ftp client where I access wordpress. How do I install tomcat to it? I am currently putting my web files in '/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs'